# Do you know some soft that can change your voice to voice of some character with neural network in real time?

Tags: audio, neural-network, voice

I need software that is able to change my voice online. Let's say I am speaking into my microphone and a man who is sitting on the other side hear the voice of Thanos, Dragon, some girl or whatever I want. 
If there is no how much time it will take to create such?

Comment: Why would it have to be a neural network?

Comment: It should not, if it works I don't mind. But I don't really think it can be made without neural network